# python: class instance can't see self attribute

Tags: python, ffi

In my project i use [module from known bt_manager](https://pythonhosted.org/BT-Manager/_modules/bt_manager/codecs.html) to decode sbc audio stream. This module is python wrap for C-functions from rtpsbc library.

```
class SBCCodec:
    def __init__(self, config):

            import sys

            try:
                self.codec = ffi.verify(b'#include "rtpsbc.h"',
                                        libraries=[b'rtpsbc'],
                                        ext_package=b'rtpsbc')
            except:
                print 'Exception:', sys.exc_info()[0]

            self.config = ffi.new('sbc_t *')
            self.ts = ffi.new('unsigned int *', 0)
            self.seq_num = ffi.new('unsigned int *', 0)
            self._init_sbc_config(config)
            self.codec.sbc_init(self.config, 0)
```

When i try to create SBCCodec class instance it gives me:

```
AttributeError: SBCCodec instance has no attribute 'codec'
```

You can see this attribute in the piece of code i posted above. It works with ffi-methods (ffi.verify, ffi.new). When i input those commands in ipython everything works correct without errors.

What have i missed?

Comment: That's because you're probably hitting your `except` clause? and that causes `self.codec` to be never set. Do you get any other error messages?

Comment: Do you see the exception printed when you run this?

Comment: yes...it's `Exception: <type 'exceptions.IOError'>`

Comment: @r_spb Cool. That means that your ffi.verify is indeed failing. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Torxed has already mentioned the only way this would happen is if *ffi.verify* inside your try block throws an exception. If that happens *self.codec* will not be initialised. If that happens your code does not rethrow the exception and continues as normal after simply printing (which is not clean behaviour). The final statement then tries to call *self.codec.config.sbc_init*, that is it assumes that *self.codec* is already intialised, which is incorrect in this particular case and that is why you get the *AttibuteError*.

If you want to create the instance anyway regardless of the failure for *ffi.verify* at the start of init define *self.codec = None* and in your final statement insert a check such as:

```
if (self.codec != None ):
   self.codec.sbc_init(self.config, 0)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I can't pass it. Manually inputed ffi.verify works fine. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that `ffi.verify` is raising an exception. Why? No idea.

Comment: @r_spb That certainly sounds like a different question to what you had asked originally but none the less. If I had to guess I'd say it could likely be the difference between where you are manually running the interpreter from and which directory you run the script. In other words maybe the working directories are different in both cases.

Comment: @siphr directory is the same

Comment: @siphr You were right: ffi methods didn't work in sys.path directory from where i uploaded modules.